# Error in pushing dataframe to db2 Database using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy, db2

I have a dataframe that is of shape `3200 x 8`. I am trying to push it to IBM's DB2 Database using sqlalchemy. One of the columns have text in it which is of variable length, think of it as English sentences/comments with emojis in it, and some other columns containing some other data types. All in all, consider the dataframe to be of a large size.

FYI, I've configured the engine and with small chunk of data it seems fine.

When I do,

```
df.to_sql(name="my_table", con=db2_engine,index=False,if_exists='append')
```

I get an error,

`DatabaseError: ibm_db_dbi::DatabaseError: Exception('SQLRowCount failed: [IBM][CLI Driver] CLI0125E  Function sequence error. SQLSTATE=HY010 SQLCODE=-99999')`

I tried the chunk option for to_sql but to no avail.

How do I fix this error?

Edit:

This is the output of my `pip freeze`

```
cachetools==4.1.0
certifi==2020.4.5.1
chardet==3.0.4
emoji==0.5.4
google-api-core==1.17.0
google-api-python-client==1.8.2
google-auth==1.14.2
google-auth-httplib2==0.0.3
google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.1
googleapis-common-protos==1.51.0
httplib2==0.17.3
idna==2.9
langdetect==1.0.8
oauthlib==3.1.0
protobuf==3.11.3
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
pytz==2020.1
requests==2.23.0
requests-oauthlib==1.3.0
rsa==4.0
six==1.14.0
uritemplate==3.0.1
urllib3==1.25.9
```

Comment: @mao, I've added the `pip freeze` in the edit, I hope this will add some details to the question?

Comment: There are 8 columns and all are of CLOB type

Comment: Do you think it is rational to store this data in No-SQL instead based on the lenghts?

Comment: See, there is a column with english sentences in it, and the length can vary from 1 word (1 or more characters) to may be any number of words (but practically lets cap it to say 500 words), as it is a real time database and I am scrape this data from the comments section of the client. Other columns will be list of some important words and emojis in the text. Hope this answer your question.
And secondly, yes the encoding for the database it UTF-8

Comment: Please get  column-lengths from Db2 catalog or from  `create table` statement. Most likely at least one row has content that Db2 is rejecting and that exception is not being handled properly (by some component), which causes the next action to throw CLI0125E.  You need to find the first row that causes your symptom , and see the real exception with CLI trace.  If you find the first row that causes the symptom, others can recreate and get the issue fixed. A CLOB  (for Db2 on Linux/Unix/Windows) can be __defined__ with size up to (2GB -1byte), but if  too short for your data then you get issues.

Answer (score 0):

Had today the same problem (reason why I found this link).

The problem appeared to be as @mao suggested there was a content that db2 was rejecting, in my instance I had a column which contained some integers and some empty strings, confusing the SQL interpreter on the actual data type to be used (int or strings).

**Solution: changed all values within the column to a string data type and it worked.**

Source on error: https://www.sqlerror.de/db2_sql_error_-804_sqlstate_07002.html